# JQuery Height of Div to increase in size Vertically

Tags: jquery, html, height

I am trying to get a div to increase in height but moving upwards instead of downwards, this happens almost every second (on a realtime event):

```
 height++;
 $("#bar").height(height);
```

But right now the top of the box stays in the same position while the bottom of the bar goes down. I want the bottom of the bar to stay where it is while the top moves up with each event. I hope this makes sense, any advice would help thank you!

UPDATE: The CSS of the bar:

```
#bar
{
 width:20px;
 height:0px;
 display: block;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` will animate bottom to top unless you attach it by the bottom css style. For example

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/BWwyf/

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

then

```
$('div').slideUp();
```

This will animate from the top to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Pete ,

Make it position absolute and give the bottom some pixel, so it always stays there

```
#bar
{
 width:20px;
 display: block;
 background-color: blue;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:2px;

}
```

make this parent div relative

Comment: @pete , i just gave 2px bottom , to tell that you that it maintains 2px from bottom.